# Get existing Account ID in flow while Lead conversion

Tags: visual-workflow

Scenario: While conversion of Lead in a record triggered flow, I am able to get converted account id. Using it I can have account owner and can assign another record to that user(account owner).
But if user chooses existing account while conversion, how to get that account id and then account owner for assignment?

Comment: Also check the [Lead object documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think `CreatedDate` field in that account object will be help us to identify the info like whether the `Account` is created as new during lead conversion [OR] that lead is merged into existing account.

In Lead record, we can use the standard field `ConvertedAccountId` to identify the `accountid` of the `converted lead` and in `flow` we can use the `Get Record` component to query the accounts by using that `ConvertedAccountId` field values.

From the `Get record` list we can pass the list values into `loop` component and check that particular account record's `Createddate` field is matched with that Converted Lead record's `LastModifieddate`.

If it's matched, it's an **New Account** record which created during Lead conversion action. otherwise, It's an **existing account** and that lead is merged into that account.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Mohanraj. Your explanation pushed me to think in right direction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
Actually ConvertedAccountId will carry the ID in both cases. I checked through logs. Whether new account from conversion process or existing account picked, Id will always be in ConvertedAccountId. And once got the ID, need to get Account, then owner User record of that account and assign the user where ever needed.